# Unable to update arch linux under proxy

Tags: arch-linux, proxy, pacman

Cannot update pacman using `sudo pacman -Syu` under proxy network.
I tried exporting environment variables using

```
export http_proxy='http://uem:12345@172.16.0.1:3128/'
```

as my workplace network uses proxy and authenticaton.

and then updating using

```
sudo -E pacman -Syu
```

but it returns `error 407`and `error: failed to synchronize any databases`

Comment: You have a missing colon in-between `http` and `//` - not sure if that's a copy-and-paste error

Comment: That really doesn't seem to be a duplicate of this at all. URI-encoding (from the comment) *may* be relevant, but the answers certainly won't be the same.

Comment: I installed wget and added proxy settings to it, this seems to be the easiest possible way to do this, but then again it returns error 503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate your issue. `sudo -E pacman -Syu` with `export http_proxy` works for me.

I would check your user and password is correct (I know it is silly but humour me).

Test with curl or wget.

If you can get one of those to work you update pacman.conf:

> XferCommand = /path/to/command %u
>
> ```
>      If set, an external program will be used to download all remote
>      files. All instances of %u will be replaced with the download URL.
>      If present, instances of %o will be replaced with the local
>      filename, plus a “.part” extension, which allows programs like wget
>      to do file resumes properly.
>
>      This option is useful for users who experience problems with
>      built-in HTTP/FTP support, or need the more advanced proxy support
>      that comes with utilities like wget.
> ```

Comment: Figured out the problem, it was simply the bandwith or say jus the network speed that was blocking me from doing this, now it works with both the way you said and the "export http_proxy..." way.